# Invariant measure for Itō diffusion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ be positive and $h\ge 0$. Assume that $g:=f'/f$ is Lipschitz continuous and let $U$ be a strong solution of $${\rm d}U_t=\frac h2g(U_t){\rm d}t+\sqrt h{\rm d}W_t$$ ($W$ being a standard Brownian motion) with $U_0\sim\mu:=f\lambda^1$ (measure with density $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^1$). Let $$\pi_{s,\:t}(x,B):=\operatorname P\left[U_t\in B\mid U_s=x\right]\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in\mathbb R\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$$ for $0\le s\le t$.

> How can we show that $\mu$ is invariant with respect to $\pi_{s,\:t}$, i.e. $$\mu\pi_{s,\:t}=\mu\tag1$$ (where the left-hand side denotes the [composition of transition kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Composition_of_kernels) for all $0\le s\le t$?

It's clear to me that $$\operatorname P\left[U_s\in\:\cdot\:\right]\pi_{s,\:t}=\operatorname P\left[U_t\in\:\cdot\:\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }0\le s\le t\tag2.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rescaling the process in time appropriately (which does not influence the invariant measures) and introducing $V$ such that $e^{-V} = f$, we can write:
$${\rm d}U_t= - V'(U_t) {\rm d}t+\sqrt {2} \, {\rm d} B_t,$$
where $B_t$ is another Brownian motion.
The associated Fokker-Planck equation,
which governs the evolution of the probability density $p(u, t)$ of $U_t$,
is
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(u, t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \left(V'(u) \, p(u, t) + \frac{\partial p}{\partial u}(u, t) \right), $$
which admits $C \, e^{-V(u)}$ as a stationary solution.
Note that the rescaling is not necessary, of course.

Comment: Do you know how we can show that the distribution of $U_t$ converges to the invariant measure (in total variation distance) in this setting? (I've asked a separate question; see EDIT 3: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057994/convergence-of-the-distribution-of-the-langevin-diffusion-to-its-invariant-measu)

Comment: Don't know about the total variation distance, but yes, it is possible to show the convergence. I'll have a look at your other question when I get the time.

Comment: Thank you. The convergence in total variation distance would follow if we could show that for each initial distribution with a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, $\nu\kappa_t$ has a density $f_t$ with respect to $\lambda$ such that $f_t\to g$ in $L^1(\lambda)$ as $t\to\infty$, where $g$ is the density from the invariant measure.

Comment: Can we say anything about uniqueness? Do we need to impose additional assumptions on $f$ to ensure that $\mu$ is the unique invariant measure?

Comment: I think all you need is the Poincaré inequality to hold in $e^{-V}$ (see my answer to your other question). Some assumptions on $V$ are required. E.g. if you have an infinite potential barrier separating the domain in 2 parts, such as $V = x^2 + 1/x^2$, then the eigenspace with 0 eigenvalue of the FP operator will have dimension 2.

Comment: So, even when we are only interested in weak convergence (in contrast to total variation convergence) we need something like the curvature dimension condition (as presented in Bakry, Gentil, Ledoux)? I'm a bit struggling which condition is weaker: In Bakry/Gentil/Ledoux, they assume $V''\ge\rho$ for some $\rho>0$. This yields a Poincaré inequality. In [Theorem 2.1 in Roberts/Tweedie](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e86f/414f860a1a70e16d9718c887f4eb59a51f62.pdf) they assume something different (and only obtain convergence in total variation, but no uniform bound).

Comment: I don't know much more than what I wrote, unfortunately. A paper that  seems to be referenced a lot on the subject of Poincaré inequalities is [this one](http://emis.ams.org/journals/EJP-ECP/_ejpecp/ECP/include/getdoc381d.pdf?id=4461&article=1975&mode=pdf). See for example corollary 1.6.

Comment: It is also possible to show convergence in relative entropy (and therefore also in $L^1$) if your measure satisfies a log-Sobolev inequality. I highly recommend having a look at the paper by Gabriel Stoltz and Tony Lelièvre (which I should read more carefully as well!), [here](http://emis.ams.org/journals/EJP-ECP/_ejpecp/ECP/include/getdoc381d.pdf?id=4461&article=1975&mode=pdf). In particular, you might find proposition 2.9 quite useful.

Comment: Ok, reading proposition 2.12 in the aforementioned paper by Stoltz & Lelièvre, it looks like the LSI (log-Sobolev inequality) implies a PI Poincaré inequality.

Comment: But the Poincaré inequality implies the convergence in total variation. This is a very strong kind of measure convergence. I had the hope that weak convergence could be shown under much weaker conditions. BTW your second link (to the paper by Stoltz and Lelièvre) is the same link as the first one. I suppose that this wasn't your intend?