# Fokker-Planck equation for a Markov semigroup with densities

Tags: partial-differential-equations, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
- $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$ and $$\kappa_tf:=\int\kappa_t(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)$$ for $$f\in F_0:=\left\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is }\mathcal E\text{-measurable and }\left(\kappa_t\left|f\right|\right)(x)<\infty\text{ for all }x\in E\text{ and }t\ge0\right\}$$
- $F\subseteq F_0$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space containing the elementary $\mathcal E$-measurable functions as a dense subset

Assume $$T(t)f:=\kappa_tf\;\;\;\text{for }f\in F\text{ and }t\ge0$$ is a $C^0$-semigroup on $F$. Let $$\operatorname{orb}f:[0,\infty)\to F\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto T(t)f$$ for $f\in F$ and $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ denote the infinitesimal generator of $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$. We know that $$\left(\operatorname{orb}f\right)'(t)=AT(t)f=T(t)Af\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\mathcal D(A)\text{ and }t\ge0.\tag1$$

---

Now, assume that there is a $\mathcal E\otimes\mathcal E$-measurable $p_t:E\times E\to[0,\infty)$ with $$\kappa_t(x,B)=\int_Bp(x,y)\lambda\left({\rm d}y\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E\tag2$$ for some measure $\lambda$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$ for all $t\ge0$. It's easy to see that $$p_{s+t}(x,\;\cdot\;)=\int p_s(x,y)p_t(y,\;\cdot\;)\lambda\left({\rm d}y\right)\;\;\;\lambda\text{-almost everywhere for all }x\in E\tag3$$ for all $s,t\ge0$.

> Does $(p_t)_{t\ge0}$ satisfy an identity like $(1)$?

I guess the answer is yes and the corresponding identity is called the *Fokker-PLanck equation*. However, I couldn't find this equation in this general setting. Clearly, we need regularity assumptions on $(p_t)_{t\ge0}$, but which assumptions do we really need to impose?

I could imagine that we're able to show something like $$\frac\partial{\partial t}p_t(x,y)=(Ap_t(x,\;\cdot\;)(y).$$

Comment: The equation at the very end of your question is known as Kolmogorov backward equation. I'm not aware of general conditions for the equation to hold, apart from the diffusion case. It already starts with the problem that it is not clear that $p$ is regular enough to be in the domain of $A$ and to admit a time derivative...

Comment: @saz Do you you have a good reference for the diffusion case?

Comment: @saz Some thoughts: Let $f∈\mathcal D(A)$ and $$u(t,x):=(T(t)f)(x)\;\;\;\text{for }(t,x)∈[0,∞)×E.$$ For fixed $t≥0$, let $$v(x):=u(t,x)\;\;\;\text{for }x∈E.$$ Since $f∈\mathcal D(A)$, $v∈\mathcal D(A)$ and $$\frac{u(t+h,\;⋅\;)-u(t,\;⋅\;)}h=\frac{T(h)v-v}h\xrightarrow{h→0}Av.$$

Comment: @saz So, if the topology induced by the norm on $F$ is coarser than the topology of pointwise convergence, then $u$ is partially differentiable in the first variable the classical sense and \begin{equation}\left\{\begin{split}\frac{∂u}{∂t}(t,x)&=(A(u(t,\;⋅\;)))(x)&\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)∈[0,∞)×E\\u(0,x)&=f(x)&\;\;\;\text{for all }x∈E.\end{split}\right.\end{equation} Is that what's meant by the backward equation?

Comment: What you just proved is (1) from your question, right? Depending on the author "Kolmogorov backward equation" can mean different things, but what I had in mind is the pointwise equation $$\partial_t p(t,x,y) = - A_y p_t(x,\cdot)(y)$$ which you mentioned at the very end of your question. Under the assumption that $p_t$ is smooth enough for the equation to make sense, you can find the proof for instance in Schillings book on Brownian motion.

Comment: @saz It's essentially $(1)$, but the convergence of the differential quotients takes place in $F$. So, I think that the topology on $F$ should need to be finer (I've mistakenly wrote coarser above) than the topology of pointwise convergence, if we want $u$ to be a solution in the classical sense.

Comment: To be honest, I've no idea what you are heading at. If $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ then $u(t,x) := T_t f(x)$ **is** a classical solution to the equation in your 3rd comment. Why do you suddently want to change the topology? How is this all related to your question about such an equation holding for the transition density?

Comment: @saz Why should it be a classical solution? We only know that $\frac{u(t+h,\;⋅\;)-u(t,\;⋅\;)}h\xrightarrow{h→0}Au(t,\;⋅\;)$ in $F$. My understanding of a classical solution is that $\frac{u(t+h,x)-u(t,x)}h\xrightarrow{h→0}Au(t,x)$ for all $x\in E$. How do you obtain that?

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry, my fault. So, yes, then the topology should be finer than  the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: @saz For simplicity, assume $(E,\mathcal E)=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. In order to differentiate $(\kappa_tf)(x)=\int p_t(x,y)f(y)\:\lambda({\rm d}y)$ under the integral sign with respect to $t$ (for a fixed $x$), we need that there is a $h\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$ with $p_t(x,\;\cdot\;)|f|\le h$ $\lambda$-almost everywhere for all $t\ge0$. Even when $f$ is bounded, this seems to be hard to verify. Is there an easy to verify condition?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Showing (pointwise) differentiability of the transition density is, in general, highly non-trivial... finding a nice dominating integrable function is obviosuly even more difficult.

Comment: @saz Hm, actually, I think that given a Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $x\in\mathbb R$, it's sufficient to show $$\forall t\ge0:\exists h\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda):\forall s\in[0,t]:p_s(x,\;\cdot\;)|f|\le h\;\lambda\text{-almost everywhere}\tag4.$$ So, if $f$ is compactly supported, it would suffice to assume that $[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R\ni(t,y)\mapsto p_t(x,y)$ is locally bounded. With $K:=\operatorname{supp}f$, we would obtain $$\forall t\ge0:\forall s\in[0,t]:p_s(x,\;\cdot\;)|f|\le\sup_{(\tilde s,\:y)\in[0,\:t]\times K}p_{\tilde s}(x,y)|f(y)|<\infty\tag5.$$

Comment: In order to differentiate under the integral sign you need a nice upper bound for the derivative of $p$. Typically the main problem is the behaviour of the derivative close to $t=0$.

Comment: @saz Sure, you're right. For some reason, I tried to bound the function itself instead of its derivative. However, my comment should still be correct, if we replace $p$ by $\partial_tp$ (assuming that $p$ is differentiable in $t$). Actually, all I'm trying to do is understanding [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3079214/47771) and why it makes sense to consider the Fokker-Planck equation therein.

Comment: @saz (What I mean above is that $[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R\ni(t,y)\mapsto\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t,x,y)$ is locally bounded.)

Comment: In general, the time derivative of the transition density of a Markov process does not need to be locally bounded (in the sense which you stated in your previous comment). If it **was** locally bounded, then indeed everything would work out quite nicely.

Comment: @saz Can we show that such a $p$ exists in the case of the Langevin diffusion?

Comment: I'm not sure; I'm not that familiar with this particular topic. I will take a look at your question when I have some spare time...